# Does an extended stay hotel qualify as "living quarters" for New York tax form IT-203?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, non-resident, new-york

I was in New York City for about 3 months last summer for an internship. During that time, I lived in an extended stay hotel (in NYC).

Item H of the New York tax form IT-203 asks whether I "had living quarters available for [my] use in New York State during any part of 2017". Does the extended stay hotel count as "living quarters"?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [instructions](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/it/it203i.pdf), it notes:

> These living quarters would
>   include a house, apartment, co‑op or any other living quarters
>   that are suitable for year-round use, maintained or paid for by
>   you or your spouse, or any living quarters maintained for your
>   use by another person, family member, or employer.

Perhaps someone more versed in New York rules than I will know for sure, but I would suggest that an extended stay hotel is *possibly* suitable for year-round use.  In this case I think it won't make a difference in your taxes - you said you only stayed there three months, so you won't be a full year resident since you were there under 183 days - so you may want to be cautious and complete Schedule B.

Comment: On the other hand, a regular hotel is also possibly "suitable for year-round use".

Comment: Hotels *are* used year-round; a single person just doesn't stay that long. Non-year-round use, I think, refers to things like non-winterized cabins or beach cottages that wouldn't be considered inhabitable during the winter. (Little or no heat or insulation, etc).

Comment: But he already is taking abut extended stay hotels.